# Why doesn't mesh analysis work here?

Tags: homework, circuit-theory

I am new to theory of circuits and I just learned about mesh analysis.  When I was doing some reviewing, I stumbled across this question and wonder if you can use it here:

[image]

I plugged the equation into my calculator and it just returned i1=i2=i3=0. Shouldn’t I be able to solve for i3 which is Io?

Comment: You do not need the equation for I1 because we already know that I1 is \$ I_1 = 15A\$.  Thus, all you need is this \$-13I_2 + 7I_1 + 4I_3 = 0\$ and \$ - 12I_3 + 4I_2 = 0\$

Answer (score 3):

Your first equation (\$-13I_1 +7I_2=0\$) is incorrect because it doesn't account for the voltage across the current source. (But because there's no way to determine the voltage across the current source from the voltage across it, you can't use a mesh equation for a mesh that contains a current source. That's okay because you know right away that \$I_1 = 13\ {\rm A}\$ so you don't need an equation for mesh 1 anyway)

Comment: Well, technically, you can just assign an unknown voltage for the current source and then you can keep all the meshes and they work just fine. Still, as you say, one of the mesh currents is known.

Comment: @periblepsis, sure the equation will still be valid, but it's not useful for solving for the mesh currents. You might want to use that equation if you're specifically asked to find the voltage across the source.

Comment: I believe it's solvable for all mesh currents. Need me to show you how? Or perhaps we are talking across each other. No way to be sure without doing the work, I guess.

Comment: @The Photon, Thank you for the effort, I see what my problem is, I didn’t account for the voltage across the current source, also, is there like a general rule for choosing a specific method on certain circuits because you mentioned mesh analysis being not useful here

Comment: @poopsalot15, Nothing wrong with using the mesh method here. You just need to treat meshes that contain a current source specially. In this case you just set \$I_1=15\ {\rm A}\$ and don't use the equation for mesh 1.

Comment: @periblepsis, yes it's solvable for all mesh currents. But the loop equation that includes the current source is not useful for getting that solution. Only the equations for the other two loops are required (along with the equation for the current source \$I_1 = 15\ A\$).

Answer (score 2):

I unintentionally solved your problem in a comment for The Photon. At that time, I was trying to make and clarify my point to him. And to do that concretely and firmly I had to solve it so there was no remaining question about where I was coming from. Since I already messed that up (but now deleted, since he can just look here) I decided I may as well codify it in an answer. So here it is.

To solve the mesh equations all you need to do is to assign an unknown voltage across the \$I_S\$ current source and call it \$V_S\$. Then quite simply proceed to write out your standard mesh equations as you would in any other case.

I may as well just lay out what I provided in LTspice to start, because I've labeled everything there:

[image]

The mesh equations are then:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+V_S-R_1\cdot I_A-R_2\cdot\left(I_A-I_B\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-R_2\cdot\left(I_B-I_A\right)-R_3\cdot I_B-R_4\cdot\left(I_B-I_C\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-R_4\cdot\left(I_C-I_B\right)-R_5\cdot I_C-R_6\cdot I_C&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

Nothing fancy there. You also happen to know that \$I_A=15\:\text{A}\$. So you can either just plug that into the above equations and solve for \$V_S\$, \$I_B\$, and \$I_C\$ (3 equations and 3 unknowns) or else you can just add one more equation, \$I_A=15\:\text{A}\$ and solve for \$V_S\$, \$I_A\$ (which will be obvious), \$I_B\$, and \$I_C\$ (4 equations and 4 unknowns, with one of them `given`, so to speak.) It's all the same thing, really.

And yes, you do need to recognize the fact that there is some voltage across the current source. It might be anything. So it's an unknown to solve for. But there's no reason why you cannot just recognize that fact and include it in your mesh loop equation set.

Mesh works just fine.

Let's solve the above using SymPy and take all four equations:

```
eq1 = Eq( 0 + vs - 6*ia - 7*(ia-ib), 0 )
eq2 = Eq( 0 - 7*(ib-ia) - 2*ib - 4*(ib-ic), 0 )
eq3 = Eq( 0 - 4*(ic-ib) - 3*ic - 5*ic, 0 )
eq4 = Eq( ia, 15 )
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ ia, ib, ic, vs ] )
{ia: 15, ib: 9, ic: 3, vs: 132}
```

That's it! 4  equations and 4 unknowns.

Now, we could have substituted in for \$I_A\$ and solved the following:

```
eq1 = Eq( 0 + vs - 6*15 - 7*(15-ib), 0 )
eq2 = Eq( 0 - 7*(ib-15) - 2*ib - 4*(ib-ic), 0 )
eq3 = Eq( 0 - 4*(ic-ib) - 3*ic - 5*ic, 0 )
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ ib, ic, vs ] )
{ib: 9, ic: 3, vs: 132}
```

That's the 3 equations and 3 unknowns variation. Either way, you get the same results.

Take your pick.